# Partial screenshot to clipboard shows a transparent layer on top

Tags: clipboard, screenshot

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to grab a section of the screen and save it to the clipboard. On pasting the grabbed image, I sometimes see a transparent layer (same color as when grabbing the screen section) persists on the screenshot. This only happens intermittently.

Are there any fixes for this issue? My Ubuntu version is 16.04.

Example of the layer (the background should be white, but there is a transparent layer on top):
[image: Example of the erroneous screenshot]

Comment: Screenshot of bad screenshot would be very useful.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the issue and get a representative screenshot.

Comment: Since the issue is intermittent, I had to wait until I could observe it again. I have updated the question with the screenshot.